# How to programmatically render custom fields in drupal 7 page.tpl.php?

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-7

What is the solution for accessing custom fields on page.tpl.php in drupal 7? I was trying the following code but it throws a "Strict Warning only variables should be passed" error.

```
 print render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_artwork',
 array('label'=>'hidden')));
```

What is the proper way to render these fields in drupal 7? Keep in mind I have 5 fields I want to move to alternate locations in page.tpl.php, one is an image and the others are text.

Comment: Avoid rendering field directly in a template, instead rely on preprocess function to inject rendered fields into your template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when you using a function call to pass its return value as parameter of another function.

So the solution is simple:

```php
$field = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_artwork',
 array('label'=>'hidden'));
print render($field);
```

Comment: this did work for me although there needed to be an additional ";" after the second line.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback :)